# Vertical spacing between character and \hat

Tags: spacing, accents

I am trying to typeset `\hat{V}` but it turns out not looking right. The hat is too close to the V so it is difficult to decipher the hat on the V. Is there a way to increase the vertical space between the V and the hat?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. With the default font, it looks good. What font are you using in math mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REVISED to work with all mathstyles.

I've set it up so that changing the value of `\dyhat` changes the vertical shift relative to its default placement.  Shown below (for all three math styles) with a 0.067ex shift on the first line, and a 0.2ex shift on the second line.  Negative shifts are acceptable.  Using a scalable shift measurement like ex's will permit the result to scale to the different math sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\stacktype{L}
\stackMath
\def\dyhat{.067ex}
\newcommand\myhat[1]{\ThisStyle{%
              \stackon[\dyhat]{\SavedStyle#1}
                              {\SavedStyle\hat{\phantom{#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\( \myhat V \)
\(\scriptstyle \myhat V \)
\(\scriptscriptstyle \myhat V \)

\def\dyhat{.2ex}
\( \myhat V \)
\(\scriptstyle \myhat V \)
\(\scriptscriptstyle \myhat V \)
\end{document}
```

[image]