# Adjusting the position of \dot

Tags: fonts, math-mode, spacing

I'm writing a paper that uses the symbol `\dot{\mathcal{U}}` which for me (in PDFLaTeX with Palatino math fonts) looks like this:

[image]

As you can imagine, from further away, the dot is invisible.  Is there some easy way of increasing the space between the character and the dot, or moving it to the right, so it's more visible?

Comment: In [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128255/symbols-for-symmetric-difference) post, the goal was decrease the space of the dot from a line.  I think the two answers should be applicable to your case just in reverse by increasing the distance.

Comment: @dustin, I think the idea is to move the dot to the right, not vertically. (At least, this is what I would think to be most appropriate.)

Comment: @SeanAllred that is what I would want but I interpreted increase space between the character and the dot as meaning vertical distance.

Comment: @dustin if only everyone thought in boxes :-) the world would be a much more TeX-friendly place

Comment: I'll just clarify: I would interested in moving the dot upward or to the right.  I think either one would improve the look.

Comment: The U seems to be drawn from the Zapf Chancery font, which is completely unapt for a math symbol font. The `palatino` package doesn't show that symbol, as it doesn't affect math. Please, add a minimal example showing how you get that output. You should try also `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` or `\usepackage{mathpazo}` for using math with the Palatino font and not `\usepackage{palatino}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new macro that provides a slightly `disp`laced `dot`, say `\dispdot[<disp>]{<stuff>}`. Below I've defined `\dispdot` to give a `.2ex` displacement. Supplying a different `<disp>` will change the location of the `\dot`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dispdot}[2][.2ex]{\dot{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+#1][\depth]{$#2$}}}% \dispdot[<displace>]{<stuff>}
\begin{document}
$d\mathcal{U}, d\dot{\mathcal{U}}, d\dispdot{\mathcal{U}}, d\dispdot[.5ex]{\mathcal{U}}$
\end{document}
```

If need be, it would be possible to [capture the math style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78872/5764).

---

For horizontal displacement, you could define `\dispdot` to give a `3mu` displacement (actually, due to symmetry it is half the actual displacement):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dispdot}[2][3mu]{\dot{#2\mkern#1}\mkern-#1}% \dispdot[<disp>]{<stuff>}
\begin{document}
$d\mathcal{U}, d\dot{\mathcal{U}}, d\dispdot{\mathcal{U}}, d\dispdot[5mu]{\mathcal{U}}$
\end{document}
```

Note that `m`ath `u`nits are very small, so adjustments will be very tiny.

Answer (score 2):

This answer originally followed the logic of [Vertical spacing between character and \hat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128249/vertical-spacing-between-character-and-hat/128253#128253), but has been revised to handle differernt math sizes, shown below in `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`.

Setting `\dydot` adjusts the vertical shift of the dot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}% IF YOU NEED IT FOR SCRIPTSTYLE MATH
\def\stacktype{L}
\stackMath
\def\dydot{.2ex}
\newcommand\caldot[1]{\ThisStyle{%
              \stackon[\dydot]{\SavedStyle\mathcal{#1}}
                              {\SavedStyle\dot{\phantom{\mathcal{#1}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\( A \caldot U \)
\(\scriptstyle A \caldot U \)
\(\scriptscriptstyle A \caldot U \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; I tried this out, and it works pretty well, though something is wrong with the sizing in subscripts.

Comment: @BenWebster  Revised to handle mathstyles.